# how to merge a shapefile with a dataframe with latitude/longitude data

Tags: r, r-sf

I am struggling with the following issue

I have downloaded the `PLUTO NYC Manhattan` `Shapefile` for the **NYC tax lots** from here https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-pluto-mappluto.page

I am able to read them in `sf` with a simple `st_read`

```
> mydf
Simple feature collection with 42638 features and 90 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 971045.3 ymin: 188447.4 xmax: 1010027 ymax: 259571.5
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs
First 10 features:
   Borough Block  Lot  CD CT2010 CB2010 SchoolDist Council ZipCode FireComp PolicePrct HealthCent HealthArea
1       MN  1545   52 108    138   4000         02       5   10028     E022         19         13       3700
```

My problem is the following: I have a dataframe as follows

```
> data_frame('lat' = c(40.785091,40.785091), 'lon' = c(-73.968285, -73.968285))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
        lat        lon
      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 40.785091 -73.968285
2 40.785091 -73.968285
```

I would like to merge this data to the `mydf` dataframe above, so that I can count how many latitude/longitude observations I have within each tax lot (remember, `mydf` is at the tax lot granularity), and plot the corresponding map of it. I need to do so using `sf`.

In essence something similar to

```
pol <- mydf %>% select(SchoolDist)
plot(pol)
```

[image]

but where the counts for each tax lot come from counting how many points in my latitude/longitude dataframe fall into them.

Of course, in my small example I just have 2 points in the same tax lot, so that would just highlight one single tax lot in the whole area. My real data contains a lot more points.

I think there is an easy way to do it, but I was not able to find it.
Thanks!

Comment: `mydf` is a `MULTIPOLYGON` object, so instead of a merge I think you want an overlay: `st_intersection(mydf, other_data_frame)` where your `other_data_frame` consists of points (ie, lat/lon pairs).

Comment: thanks for helping. no but the point is that I need to aggregate these latitude/longitude points by boundary. The most natural thing in this setup, is to aggregate by the smallest boundary available in my shapefile, which is a tax lot. Therefore, I need to kind of merge these latitude longitude points to `mydf` to make the aggregation. That is, In each tax lot, I will have a number that says : there are 4 observations whose lat/long falls into this tax lot.

Comment: Okay, I see, but the aggregation is a separate step. I would overlay first, count by tax lot.

Comment: For example: `mydf %>% sf::st_intersection(other_sf) %>% dplyr::group_by(Lot) %>% dplyr::mutate(n=n())` where `other_sf = sf::st_as_sf(other_df, ...)`

Comment: interesting solution. do you mind posting this as an aswer as well? thanks!

Comment: Sure, though I have not tested it (and there's a typo!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I would do it with arbitrary polygon and point data. I wouldn't merge the two and instead just use a geometry predicate to get the counts that you want. Here we:

1. Use the built in `nc` dataset and transform to `3857` crs, which is projected rather than lat-long (avoids a warning in `st_contains`)
2. Create 1000 random points within the bounding box of `nc`, using `st_bbox` and `runif`. Note that `st_as_sf` can turn a data.frame with lat long columns into `sf` points.
3. Use `lengths(st_contains(polygons, points)` to get the counts of points per polygon. `sgbp` objects created by a geometry predicate are basically "for each geometry in `sf` x, what indices of geometries in `sf` y satisfy the predicate". So `lengths1` effectively gives the number of points that satisfy the predicate for each geometry, in this case number of points contained within each polygon.
4. Once the counts are in the `sf` object as a column, we can just `select` and plot them with the `plot.sf` method.

For your data, simply replace `nc` with `mydf` and leave out the call to `tibble`, instead use your `data.frame` with the right lat long pairs.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
nc <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf") %>%
  read_sf() %>%
  st_transform(3857)
set.seed(1000)
points <- tibble(
  x = runif(1000, min = st_bbox(nc)[1], max = st_bbox(nc)[3]),
  y = runif(1000, min = st_bbox(nc)[2], max = st_bbox(nc)[4])
) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 3857)

plot(nc$geometry)
plot(points$geometry, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
nc %>%
  mutate(pt_count = lengths(st_contains(nc, points))) %>%
  select(pt_count) %>%
  plot()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: thanks that is interesting. I just have a hard time undestanding how that can work with my shapefile (look at the `proj4string`). Also, you do not have latitude/longitude points in your example. I think this complicates the problem a bit as well

Comment: I do have latitude longitude points, the `points <-` call is just generating 1000 lat-long points within the bounding box of `nc`. I am not sure what about your `proj4string` would prevent this from working? See that I use `st_transform` to put both the polygons and points into the same CRS. I can download and try on your data in a little while

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ If you're worried about projections, use `st_set_crs` or `st_transform` to give both shapefiles/`sf` objects the same projection

Comment: As far as I can tell it works exactly the same with your data, it's just hard to see what the plot looks like because so many of the polygons are so small. I also changed the code so now it technically isn't making lat long points, but see `st_transform` and how it reprojects geometries.

Comment: thanks! so what you are saying is that I can directly use my lat/lot dataframe as the tibble `points`  in `mutate(pt_count = lengths(st_contains(mydf, points))) ` ?

Comment: No, you need to take the lat/lon dataframe and use `st_as_sf` on it so it is also an `sf` object. Make sure you specify `coords` correctly and `crs = 4326`. You should also `st_transform` both `mydf` and the resulting `points` to a common crs, `3857` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on your data, but the intersection is empty for the both sets of points you provided. However, the code should work.

**EDIT:** Simplified `group_by` + `mutate` with `add_count`:

```
mydf = st_read("MN_Dcp_Mappinglot.shp")
xydf = data.frame(lat=c(40.758896,40.758896), lon=c(-73.985130, -73.985130))
xysf = st_as_sf(xydf, coords=c('lon', 'lat'), crs=st_crs(mydf))
## NB: make sure to st_transform both to common CRS, as Calum You suggests
xysf %>% 
    sf::st_intersection(mydf) %>% 
    dplyr::add_count(LOT)
```

Reproducible example:

```
nc = sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
ncxy = sf::st_as_sf(data.frame(lon=c(-80, -80.1, -82), lat=c(35.5, 35.5, 35.5)), 
           coords=c('lon', 'lat'), crs=st_crs(nc))
ncxy = ncxy %>% 
           sf::st_intersection(nc) %>%
           dplyr::add_count(FIPS)

## a better approach
ncxy = ncxy %>%
           sf::st_join(nc, join=st_intersects) %>%
           dplyr::add_count(FIPS)
```

The new column `n` includes the total number of points per `FIPS` code.

```
ncxy %>% dplyr::group_by(FIPS) %>% dplyr::distinct(n)
> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes 
  that they are planar
  # A tibble: 2 x 2
  # Groups:   FIPS [2]
    FIPS     n
   <fctr> <int>
  1  37123     2
  2  37161     1
```

I'm not sure why your data results in an empty intersection, but since the code works on the example above there must be a separate issue.

HT: `st_join` approach from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273256/54131).

Comment: I have updated the lat/lon so that they are in central park. does that work for you now? isnt there a typo in your code? you are not using `mydf` at all. thanks!

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo. I can check it tomorrow, or you can try it and see if it works.